# How do I give access to View Bulk Data Load Job Details on a read only profile

Tags: data-loader, bulk

I need to provide access to View Bulk Data Load Job Details on a read only profile is that possible and how? please advice and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a permission set, you cannot do this at the profile level since the Read Only Profile is a standard profile.

Create a permission set with the "Manage Data Integrations" system permission, and assign the permission set to the desired users.

Salesforce Documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is not available on Salesforce Platform user license.

Comment: What user license are they? Might be able to help you find another solution. :)

Comment: User License is Salesforce Platform and I don't see Manage Data Integrations on permission set with this license :-(

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(. Could you please mark the answer as correct since it is the correct answer for those without your licensing situation?